# QSslSocket::startServerEncryption fails with "PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:bad password read"

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, openssl, qsslsocket

I've created an SSL server using the sample code from the Qt documentation. I then connect to it using `QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted`.

The server fails, however, and this is in `QSslSocket::errorString()`

```
Cannot provide a certificate with no key, 
error:0907B068:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:bad password read
```

I set the certificate and private keys with this code:

```
serverSocket->setLocalCertificate("/home/user/Workspace/openssl/cacert.pem");
serverSocket->setPrivateKey("/home/user/Workspace/openssl/privkey.pem");
```

I created the `cacert.pem` and `privkey.pem` using this command on Ubuntu:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -out cacert.pem -outform PEM -days 1825
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was because I didn't specify the password for the private key (the one that openssl asked me for during the certificate creation). So instead of

```
serverSocket->setPrivateKey("/home/user/Workspace/openssl/privkey.pem");
```

I now call

```
serverSocket->setPrivateKey("/home/user/Workspace/openssl/privkey.pem", QSsl::Rsa, QSsl::Pem, "mypassword");
```

and this fixes the problem.